# GeoServer layer not visible

Tags: geoserver, debian, datastore

I have installed a copy of GeoServer version 2.22.2 on a Debian machine.
I had made all the necessary settings for the server, I added some data to the GeoServer.

The problem comes after I reboot the machine. GeoServer is losing the layers and the stores. The only one that it stands is the workgroup, which does not disappear.
When I try to add the store and/or the layer, if I am using the same name for it, it will say that the layer/store already exists.
Do you have any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: How did you install geoserver? Where is the data directory? Is the example data still present?

Comment: I just added the geoserver to webapps folder in tomcat. sample folder not available anymore. data directory is in geoserver/data/

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: Did you use JDK 17 in combination with the "bin" packaging, by any chance?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: no. I had used the war file.

Comment: as much I can see, is a problem with user limitations. I don't know how to manage it... I mean, the user that is running on the machine does not have necessary permissions even if I give them already